# Can java script add the contents below to a table aswell

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, html

Can java script add the contents below to a asp table aswell at the same time (with html tags)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('button').click(function () {
            var x = $('textarea').val();
            $('textarea').val('');
            $('#test1').append('<div id="test">' + x + '</div>');
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>

<textarea style="border: 0" cols="77" rows="2">Write Something....</textarea>
<button>Post Message</button>
<div id="test1"></div>
</asp:Content>
```

something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('button').click(function () {
            var x = $('textarea').val();
            $('textarea').val('');
            $('#test1').append('<div id="test">' + x + '</div>');
            //$save append aswell to Table1
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('button').click(function () {
            var x = $('textarea').val();
            $('textarea').val('');
            var newdiv = $("<div></div>").html(x).attr('id','test');
            $('#test1').append(newdiv);
            $('#Table1').append(newdiv);
            //$save append aswell to Table1
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: thats the one but no contents seem to be showing in my asp table? :S

Comment: No I dont think append works on any asp control eeeekkk my on the fly method is failing hard here!!

Comment: to append to an asp.net control, you need to use the control.ClientID property which contains the actual HTML element id to use on the client side.

Comment: $("#<%= Label1.ClientID %>").append(newdiv); if i try that it doesnt work

Comment: If you inspect the DOM using the developer tools in your browser of choice, can you see the div there?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are using **jquery** here.

Have you got your jquery framework loaded & tried your code to see if it works??

[It is running fine on jsfiddle.net here](http://jsfiddle.net/2dApR/)

**Updates**

If your Table1 is on the same page.
All you need to do is to get hold of the DOM element.
if you have a table

```
<table id="Table1">
<tr><td>1</td></tr>
<tr><td>2</td></tr>
<tr><td>3</td></tr>
</table>
```

You can add after your code

```
$('#test1').append('<div id="test">' + x + '</div>');
```

this code

```
$('#Table1 tr:last').after('<tr><td>'+ x +'<td></tr>');
```

Hope you find this helpful

Comment: yes sorry, this works fine all I want to do is add another line of code so it sends the same output (that it would to my aspx) but also send the contents to a asp table

Comment: do you want to send this back to your server? It sounds like you need an ajax call here to POST your data back to your server?

Comment: see edits im trying to send the same data it sends to my page to a asp table called table1